# Get list of files as an output of script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am running a shell script which runs multiple jars and as a result, writes into different files located in different directories.

I want to get list of files created in a directory as an output of running the script in the last run.

I have my file name as `date_time_ABC.txt`. I thought of getting the file names by date but on a particular date I may run it many times, so I will get all the files including the ones created in previous runs also.

Is there a way I can get the list of the files which are generated after running the shell script. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea. Keep 2 directories - one with files touched by script (work directory) and second with synced files (mirror directory).  Put on the first line of script syncing command:

```
rsync -xrlptgoEvv /home/user/work/ /home/user/mirror/
```

and at the end of script command to detect difference between `work` and `mirror` directories with redirection of output to a plain text file:

```
diff -rq /home/user/work/ /home/user/mirror/ > /home/user/list-of-files.txt
```

You can additionally filter output of `diff` command with `sed`, `awk` etc. to have necessary format of your data. Also consider `--delete` option with `rsync` to remove from `mirror` directory files which have been deleted from `work` directory since last synchronization.

**UPDATE.** The better way possibly is to create list of files on top of script:

```
ls -la /home/user/work/ > /home/user/list-of-files.txt
```

and on bottom of script append new list of files to old list, sort it and filter unique lines which will represent new files only:

```
ls -la /home/user/work/ >> /home/user/list-of-files.txt
cat /home/user/list-of-files.txt | sort | uniq -u > /home/user/list-of-new-files.txt
```

Comment: @ArchitGoyal You're welcome! Please, see updated version of answer.

Answer (score 1):

if your *time* does not contain *second*, you could use `ls` with `-u` option:

> -u     with -lt: sort by, and show, access time; with -l: show access time and sort by name; otherwise: sort by access time, newest first

otherwise, you could list current files with `ls -u -1>../Before` and run it again after your code `ls -u -1 > ../After` then use  `comm -3 ../After ../Before` and do your job

Comment: I need to automate the process and generate the files in the script and then copy the files generated to other machine and use it. When the files are generated, there may be multiple files generated on that day. How can I segregate them by test run and get the file list

Comment: first please test above and let me know the result. thanks.